# Converting bytes to string with signed bytes

Tags: java

Is there a way to retain a signed byte when converting it to a string? Or alternatively make them be seen as unsigned when converting to a string?

Here is my code for example:

```
byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[RX_Index];
System.arraycopy(RX_Buffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
final String data = new String(encodedBytes);
```

RX_Buffer will contain 0xBF which is -65 signed decimal. After intializing data that 0xBF byte is changed to 0xFFFD after converting to a string for some reason. I'm assuming the problem is the conversion from bytes to string with a negative number. If that can't be the case let me know. Otherwise how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, you can copy it as bits to integer and then it will be positive number.

Comment: @LeosLiterak But if I then convert those integers to strings won't they become ASCII characters? For example 0x04 will become 0x34 which I don't want to happen

Comment: Is your data a binary stream, or is it text? You should not try to store binary data in a String, and you should not try to store text in a byte[].

Comment: @slartidan This is for android and the bytes are being received from an input stream via a bluetooth connection. As far as I know there is no other way to read the input stream other than bytes so storing text in bytes is not a choice. I have to receive binary data and text data--I don't have a choice

Comment: InputStream returns ints, not bytes.

Comment: @LeosLiterak My mistake, I've been using inputstreamname.read(bytesname), didn't realize inputstreamname.read() would return integers

Comment: so is your issue resolved? There is no need for precision loss / signess tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your android `BlootoothSocket` (method `read(byte[])`) will give you a byte array with binary data.

Do not convert that data to a String.

If you want the binary data to be interpreted as ints use this code:

```
int myFirstValue = encodedBytes[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

A byte is an 8bit signed type. A char is a 16bit unsigned type.

That String constructor treats the given bytes as character data encoded in the [default character encoding](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) - on Android that is UTF-8. It will transcode those bytes to UTF-16. Anything that doesn't match a valid value or sequence in the original encoding is replaced by [the replacement string](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#replacement%28%29).

So unlike in some languages Java Strings are not binary safe. Consider Base64 encoding the values if you need to store the data as a string.